# Jquery Best Practice - Putting DOM Element in Variable regardless of how many times it was used

Tags: jquery

While browsing for some best practices on Jquery, I stumbled into this one.

**Reference:** http://gregfranko.com/jquery-best-practices/#/13

```
// Stores the live DOM element inside of a variable
  var elem = $("#elem");

  // Set's an element's title attribute using it's current text
  elem.attr("title", elem.text());

  // Set's an element's text color to red
  elem.css("color", "red");

  // Makes the element fade out
  elem.fadeOut();
```

It says it's the best to `CACHE YOUR SELECTORS IN VARIABLES`

Then while working, I thought to myself, do I really have to put `#current-contact-info` and `#list-contact-form` on a variable?

Since I'm just calling it once, does it affect the performance?

**Option 1:**

```
$("#edit-contact-list").on("click", function() {
    $("#current-contact-info").addClass("hide");
    $("#list-contact-form").removeClass("hide");
});
```

Or option 2 is the best way regardless of how many times it was called?

**Option 2:**

```
$("#edit-contact-list").on("click", function() {

    var current_contact_info = $("#current-contact-info");
    var list_contact_form = $("#list-contact-form");

    current_contact_info.addClass("hide");
    list_contact_form.removeClass("hide");
});
```

I was kind of insecure on the amount of line of code though.

Comment: "amount of line of code", what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always consider simplicity and readability along with performance/best practices. Storing a element in variable is of no use if it will be used only once, also it wont help in making code more simple/readable.
I always prefer

```
 $("#current-contact-info");.addClass("hide");
 $("#list-contact-form").removeClass("hide");
```

over

```
var current_contact_info = $("#current-contact-info");
var list_contact_form = $("#list-contact-form");

current_contact_info.addClass("hide");
list_contact_form.removeClass("hide");
```

If you are worried about lines of code (it deosnt really matter though), you can achieve it in 1 line. Use [`toggleClass`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) over `addClass`/`removeClass` and use OR operator in selector

```
 $("#current-contact-info, #list-contact-form").toggleClass("hide");
```

Answer (score 2):

"cache" implies the intention to reuse the data later. If you use it only once, this is not needed.

In your case however, it is not clear how many times the click might occur. If more than once, then you could consider caching your elements as follows (outside the click event handler):

```
var current_contact_info = $("#current-contact-info");
var list_contact_form = $("#list-contact-form");

$("#edit-contact-list").on("click", function() {
  current_contact_info.addClass("hide");
  list_contact_form.removeClass("hide");
});
```